# Response every quarter between times

Tags: asp-classic

I have two dates

```
strFrom = formatDateTime("11:15",4)
strTo = formatDateTime("16:30",4)
```

I want to generate a script so that get every quarter from strFrom to StrTo

```
11:15
11.30
11.45
12.00
12:15
12:30
12:45
13:00
13:15
...
...
...
16:00
16:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need convert to a datetime, then you need to increment the minutes in a loop.

```
<%
strFrom = formatDateTime("11:15",4)
strTo = formatDateTime("16:30",4)

dteFrom=CDate(strFrom)
dteTo=CDate(strTo)

Response.write(strFrom & "<br>")
Do While (dteFrom < dteTo)
    dteFrom=DateAdd("n",15,dteFrom)
    Response.write(formatDateTime(dteFrom,4) & "<br>")  
Loop
%>
```